# Idiomatic way to handle tagged union type using a tag lookup structure

Tags: javascript, flow-typed

This is tough to describe, but see my [flow.org/try snippet](https://flow.org/try/#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-bJoADuID0l2I4jg3AV2Qoqo5+J1pNp8NDsAgfPYeiFkA1MHmcC6GAAPMnUGZKABtXjm1BW2329JDFvoaOx+NrEIASF4QO8Y5gWBAEAgAhYIgwMCYKwXB3avLWvWIEBZruy-QAukagQBlEAwGRrJZny4EFBj7w5vpmhDF-Nt1P5uD8uBFyclhsVIeNDdpgOD4EQpANoKf5vta3jqvu3iPFMUjQcKbaGEejQAEIKCAkYwGIIgQGeF4CMRIQwCwxCwNG8Y2Gw-AvjEYhzggD40ECubDK+CBRmelCft+v7Cg2ACMQFcU+PEwXx0agcilAgUi4EkFgUEvrJ-HwUikmNGhJb8QpSFCE8GCoZpwr8ZhQA) for minimal reproducing code example.

My actual code that the snippet is stripped down from has many more types and operations, but the core idea is there at the bottom - remember an association between the record and the type operations lookup. The JavaScript is sound and theoretically provable, but Flow doesn't seem to have the capability to handle this operation.

I've run into a couple of variants to this problem of how to handle tagged union types, and my goal is to organize the `display` and other operations by types to make maintaining the different records easier. Past approaches involve using switch (or if/else) statements to perform type refinement on the `type` field, but those get unwieldy as the number of types and operations stack up (I have over 30 types and over 6 different operations by now).

My hope is that Flow's branch analysis and type refinement capabilities could handle this code, given that there are a finite number of subtypes for `MyRecord` (we're not solving the halting problem here, only practically proving soundness).

I was going to post to GitHub as this may be a Flow development issue, but I wanted to start at StackOverflow since maybe there's a better way to structure this code.

Answer (score 0):

```js
declare var arr: Array<string | number>;

(arr[0]: string|number); // string or number

// But:
declare var tupleArr: [string | number];

(tupleArr[0]: string); // string only
```

[Flow.js Tuple Types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/tuples/)

[Try flow.js](https://flow.org/try/#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-bJoADuID0l2I4jg3AV2Qoqo5+J1pNp8NDsAgfPYeiFkGRlAA2nsYBgQMQli0a4owATYMR8zBDsj5nBuwAeNBmXjm1BW2329JDIfoaOx+NrMIAXSNQIAyiAYDI1ks15cCChvPuc30zQhi-mR6n83B+XAi1hhWWKouaJPMDh8ERSGXBXeSyPvOr528R4pikb9hRHQwl0aAAhBQQEjGAxBECA1w3ARkJCGAWGIWBo3jGw2H4E8YjEFgRAQbxjSPYZTwQKM10oS9r1ve8AEYn1zGif3zejX1LcNUD498SCwL8T24ujo3-JFAOAiRQPE4V6MgytnBwYAoHSGB2DgAwgA)

Comment: Unfortunately (and perhaps the example didn't make this clear), this truly is an array of generic types - they could be anything, and there could be a lot more than two of them. I'll update the example for clarity.